# C programming to store 64 bit value in a register by having 8 bit inputs each time

Tags: c++, c, embedded

I am planning to take 64 bit input basically with 8 bits inputs each time.The problem, i've encountered is that, I've a register of 64 bit where these 8 bits are being written.The 8 bits gets overlapped in 64 bit register each time in the iteration. Need a solution to this.

```
int main(){
int Status;i=9;
u64 input=0x0,read_data,input_value=0x0;

print("\r\nEnter 64 bit value:");

while(i--){
      input = inbyte();
      if (isalpha(input)) {
           input = toupper(input);
      }
      input = atoh(&input);
      input_value=input;
}

xil_printf("input = 0x%x\r\n",input_value);
```

Finding difficulty in storing and reading 64 bit value.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: Please format your code to make it readable. input_value is overwritten on each iteration because you overwrite it: `input_value=input`.

Comment: roll old value left 8 bits, then OR in the new value

Comment: Read about the bit-wise operators in your beginner-level C programming book.

Answer (score 1):

Since you overwrite `input_value` in each loop, you'll loose the previous read input.

You need to do some shifting and bit-wise or.

Assuming the input is MSB first, simply do:

```
// input_value=input;               // Replace this line with the two below
input_value = input_value << 8;     // Shift 8 bit right 
input_value = input_value | input;  // Bitwise or'ing of the new input
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always bitshift the current input_value by 8 bits and do an bitwise or ( | )  operation to add the next 8 bits to it.

```
input_value = (input_value << 8) | input;
```